# Android Speech-To-Text : option to remain it active after speech stops

Tags: android

On default it stops recording almost instantly if pause happens.
Is there an option to remain it active more time when speech stops ?
I searched docs and didn't find such option, however it seems for me, that it should be.
So, want to double check.
Thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it this way :

- changed setText to append ;
- added one more Record button right into the form, where text appears.

Now user can take pauses as much as s/he wants and then just append more speeches into the same EditText form.